What are the rules on carrying dairy produce in checked luggage when transiting airside in the EU?
I want to take 1kg of cheddar cheese from the UK to Cuba. I’m aware that it is not allowed to bring any meat or dairy products with you when travelling to the EU from a non-EU country.
Is it permitted if transiting airside? I have searched but can’t find a definitive rule that refers to transit rather than entry. Or am I splitting hairs and ‘travelling to’ should be interpreted as including airside transit?

Where do you transit? are you sure you will stay airside without going through customs or security again?

@meego Germany. And yes, I am 100% sure I will not clear customs / Immigration. I will have a fully connecting ticket (one PNR) so I will stay airside and my hold luggage will be checked through to Cuba. Occasionally the inbound flight from UK routes me through Security, but I am not concerned about that because the cheese will not be in my carry on bags.

I can't find a definitive answer but as far as I can see the main issue would be if you tried to smuggle the cheese into the country - if you were to declare it if asked and it was to be confiscated then that would be the end of the matter. If that's an acceptable risk for you (possible seizure and loss of the goods) then I don't see any reason not to, especially as you are not intending to introduce the cheese into the EU at any point. Obviously if there are any issues with delays to your flight and you need to fly the following day then you must declare the cheese if you go through customs. Both the German and French customs websites talk explicitly about "Imports" of dairy products but as you are not intending to import the cheese it's difficult to say 100% that it is relevant to your case.
As a possible workaround, if the cheese is a key part of your journey, but it isn't a particular brand or anything (you want to take cheddar as a gift rather than a particular type from a local producer, for example), then would you be able to fly via Ireland? Cheddar is widely available there and as it's originated inside the EU there would be no issues at all flying to Germany and even taking it through customs etc.

Thanks for the suggestion, but flying UK > Ireland > Germany > Cuba isn’t an option (cost, plus length of flight). The cheese is for personal consumption in Cuba, to supplement the scarce food supplies where I stay.

The safest course of action is to assume you cannot bring the cheese. The risk of confiscation is significant enough that it's best to avoid bringing it altogether.
Or you can...
Check if cheddar or similar cheeses are available in Cuba. This might be the easiest option. While potentially more expensive and time-consuming, shipping the cheese directly to your destination in Cuba (if allowed by Cuban customs) could be a safer alternative.
So basically while the rules explicitly refer to entering the EU, the practical realities of airport security and baggage handling mean that transiting with restricted items like dairy can still result in confiscation.

I wouldn’t be planning on taking cheese to Cuba for personal consumption if it were readily available there. Shipping it isn’t an option, for one thing it would be far too likely to be ‘lost’ on arrival.
